# How to alter and update large table to add composite key columns form another table

Tags: mysql, mariadb, alter-table

We have two very large tables in our Mysql(MariaDb) database. Table_1 holds a many to many map. It has a auto incremented primary key and a composite key of two columns.
Table_2 refers to the primary key of Table_1. We wan't to fix this obvious error in design by,

1. Use a composite primary key on Table_1
2. Add the two columns to Table_2
3. Populate the composite key in Table_2 by copying data from Table_1, and create index on it.
4. Preferably delete the auto incremented key column from both tables.

These tables have ~300M rows, and the tables are ~10GB range in size. We need to make these updates within a ~6 hour service window.
I'm investigating how to do this efficiently and doing trials on a replica db. So far I have not tried to run anything with actual data, because ordinary scripts would be insufficient.
I'm not an experienced DB admin. So I need some light shedding to get this done.
**My question is what would be the best approach/tips to do this efficiently?**

## Things I have attempted so far

I read about the new [instant add column](https://mariadb.com/resources/blog/instant-add-column-for-innodb/) feature, but our production DB is on MariaDb version 10.0, which is older.

I have followed suggestions in [this answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/124733) and ran below script on a latest DB version with instant add column support(Alter table was instant). The table had ~50M rows (1/6th of original). It took about two hours , that also is excluding creating new indexes. Therefore this would not be sufficient.

```
SET join_buffer_size = 4 * 50 * 1024 * 1024; -- 50M keys of 4 bytes each
SET optimizer_switch='mrr=on,mrr_cost_based=off,mrr_sort_keys=on,optimize_join_buffer_size=on';
SET join_cache_level = 8;

UPDATE TABLE_2
        JOIN  TABLE_1 ON TABLE_1_Id = TABLE_2_FKT1_Id 
SET 
    TABLE_2_KeyPart_1 = TABLE_1_KeyPart_1,
    TABLE_2_KeyPart_2 = TABLE_1_KeyPart_2
```

Also considering evaluating this tool
https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/2.2/pt-online-schema-change.html

Comment: Can you use partitions ? Then do it partition by partition ? If not, here is an idea to chunk it  : http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/deletebig#deleting_in_chunks

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion @DanielE. We'll look into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plan A:  Use Percona's tool:  `pt-online-schema-change`.

Plan B:  Use a competing product:  `gh-ost`.

Plan C:  Don't use `UPDATE`, that is the killer.  Instead, rebuild the table(s) in a straightforward way, then use `RENAME TABLE` to swap the new version into place.

Partitioning is unlikely to help in any way.  Daniel's link helps with doing a lengthy `UPDATE`, but trades off time (it takes longer) versus invasiveness (which is not an issue because you have a maintenance window).

Some more details into Plan C (which I prefer for *this* case):

```
CREATE TABLE(s) ... -- with new names, and all the new features except secondary indexes
INSERT INTO new SELECT ... FROM old table(s)
RENAME TABLE real1 TO old1,
             new1 TO real1,
             real2 TO old2,
             new2 TO real2;
test -- you still undo the RENAME if necessary
DROP TABLE old1, old2;
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions! Yes, we would like to do it without external tools if possible. So I'll start with plan C.